# syntax error at or near "JOIN" for postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-10, postgresql-12

I am trying to join two tables, and for some reason I keeping getting:

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "JOIN"

My code is:

```
SELECT
    c.visit,
    d.cake
FROM 
    customer c, 
INNER JOIN desert d 
    ON c.visit = d.visit
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: You have a comma before `INNER`.  I'm voting to close as a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comma is unnecessary:

```
SELECT
    c.visit,
    d.cake
FROM 
    customer c -- here
INNER JOIN desert d 
    ON c.visit = d.visit
LIMIT 10;
```